# Release OpenCV Mat from memory

Tags: opencv, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a sequence of images (frames) from a camera as an input, which is stored in a `std::queue<cv::Mat> buffer` container. After the algorithm is processed a frame then it is popped. 
My problem is that somehow the memory usage is constantly rising, however the container size `buffer.size()` is maximum 1 (meaning that the algorithm is 'eating' up the buffer properly and pops the images).

I would like demonstrate my problem  with a  *minimal reproducible code*:

**thread1**:
where `buffer = std::queue<cv::Mat>` is shared between threads

```
while(true)
{
    mutex->lock();
    buffer->push(cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_16UC3));
    mutex->unlock()
}
```

**main thread**:

```
while(true)
{
    if(!buffer.empty())
    {
        mutex.lock()
        buffer.pop();
        mutex.unlock()
    }
}
```

This code results in constantly rising memory usage. (Ubuntu system, opencv 3.4.6 version)

My question is that how can you properly release a `cv::Mat` from memory.

Comment: You don't have to do anything, it acts as shared pointer. When the destructor is called, reference count is decremented. When the reference count reaches zero, the memory is deallocated. Even that explicit call to `release` you have in the loop is redundant.

Comment: How can you determine the reference count? I assume, that something is referencing the memory even after popping it from queue. @DanMašek

Comment: [`cv::Mat::u`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L2103) which is a pointer to `cv::UMatData`. You're gonna have to dig through the code a bit to grok it (also `mat.inl.hpp` and `matrix.cpp`). | However, if the almost-mcve (adding includes and putting the code inside `main()`) runs out of memory, something is really wrong and it's not your code. It works fine over here (on a different platform).

Comment: @DanMašek could you please put one part of the code in a *new thread*? For example the pushing part, and the popping part in another thread? In that case there is memory leak in my system, however it is true if you simply put it in the main there is no problem.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue either, as far as I know. I have several production apps that run 24/7 where I send `Mat` objects (usually as a part of a bigger structure, but that shouldn't matter) between threads.

Comment: Really interesting! Then I will try it in another system. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There was a bug in the camera software that somehow influenced this part of code. Now it is solved. Thanks a lot!